# onclick() function for multiple checkbox select

Tags: javascript, php

I need a way by which I can get multiple checkbox selects, I know that there is an onclick event by which i can do it but that is just for single checkbox. Thanks in advvance

Comment: Show us what code you have so far.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "get multiple checkbox selects"?

Comment: Say I have `<input type="checkbox" name="same_day" value="value" id="same_day"> Same day` `<input type="checkbox" name="8-hours" value="8-hours" id ="8_hours"> 8-hours` and a few more checkboxes. Now I need to call onClick() event whenever a checkbox is clicked, so now if I call onclick on Same Day checkbox, it will call onclick only when i click on Same Day but I need to get all the clicked values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<form action="url" method="post" id="form">
    <input type="checkbox" name="box" id="box1" value="checkVal1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="box" id="box2" value="checkVal2" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var value = $("input[type='checkbox']").val();
        console.log(value);
    })
})
```

This should work.

Comment: I tweaked your answer a bit, but it worked. Thanks @Robert

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code which give an array with multiple check box id. You can use the array asper your requirement.  Run it in your machine you will get the clear concept

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var arr = new Array();
        function createArr(id){
            var chkBoxId =  document.getElementById("arr_"+id);

            if(chkBoxId.checked){
                arr.push(chkBoxId.value);
            } else{
                for(var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if(arr[i] === chkBoxId.value) {
                       arr.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            alert(arr); // here you will get your array with multiple checkbox Id and you can use it
        }
    </script>
    <form name="CreateArray" id="CreateArray" method="post">
    <?php
        for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
    ?>
    <?php echo $i.".";?>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="arr[]" value="<?php echo $i?>" id="arr_<?php echo $i?>" onclick="createArr(<?php echo $i?>);"/>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's using jQuery:

```
$('.select-all').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            CheckAll();
    });

function CheckAll() {
    $("#checkboxes input").each( function() {
        $(this).attr("checked",status);
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<p><a href="#" class="select-all">Select All</a></p>


<div id="checkboxes">
<p><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="1" /> Hijo de Satan</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="1" /> Hijo de Satan</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="1" /> Hijo de Satan</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="1" /> Hijo de Satan</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="1" /> Hijo de Satan</p>
</div>
```

Check this example:

http://examples.arturito.net/jquery/selectall/

Comment: Or, without `each`, you could do `$("#checkboxes input").prop("checked",status);`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way its to use a Framework like jQuery and basically you have 3 options, wherever the option you use you can use ":checkbox" as your selected as the sample below, just have in mind that .live will attach the event even when you add new checboxes dynamically if its your case.

.click

```
$( "#YourCheckBoxID" ).click(function() {
  alert( "User clicked on Checkbox" );
});
```

.bind

```
$( "#YourCheckboxID" ).bind( "click", function() {
  alert( "User clicked on Checkbox" );
});
```

.live

```
$(":checkbox").live('click', function() {
    alert('User clicked on Checkbox');
});
```

Regards.

Comment: I can not upvote your answer as I am a new user. But thank you so much.